# Почему дело выгорает?

Tags: фразеология

Когда хотят сказать, что нечто успешно проделано, говорят, что "дело выгорело". Правда, фраза эта носит немного негативный оттенок - скорее, так говорят о какой-нибудь афере.
А почему именно "выгорело"? Это от какого-то воровского жаргона? Откуда вообще пошло выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одно из вполне приемлемых объяснений:

http://fun.ucoz.ru/news/2000-11-11-120

ДЕЛО ВЫГОРЕЛО
Дореволюционный неправый суд дал нашей речи немало горьких и язвительных крылатых выражений. 
Пользуясь ими, мы часто не знаем, что за ними стоит. 
Нередко слышишь: "Ну, мое дело выгорело", - то есть я добился своего, победил. А ведь в этих словах живет память о вопиющем безобразии прошлого. В старину бывали случаи, когда судебный процесс останавливался: виноватого нельзя было наказать, а правого оправдать, если внезапно пропадало судебное "дело" - документы, хранившиеся в суде. 
Помните удивительный случай, рассказанный Н. В. Гоголем в повести о ссоре двух друзей? Бурая свинья Ивана Ивановича вбежала в суд и съела жалобу, которую на ее хозяина подал его бывший друг Иван Никифорович... Разумеется, это всего-навсего веселая выдумка. А вот сгорали бумаги в судах довольно часто, и, бывало, не случайно. И тогда человек, которому было необходимо затянуть или прекратить дело, посмеивался себе в бороду и, очень довольный, повторял про себя: "Слава богу, мое дело выгорело!" 
Вот откуда пошли эти странно звучащие слова: дела-то выгорали не сами по себе, а по просьбе судившегося, за хорошую плату - взятку.

Comment: Если сравнивать с современным судом, то дореволюционный был очень даже правый...

Comment: Достаточно вспомнить дело Засулич, чтобы подивиться справедливости дореволюционного суда.

Answer (score 0):

«Дело выгорело (у кого). Разг. Кто-л. добился своего, все устроил. ЗС 1996, 122; БМС 1998, 148. Большой словарь русских поговорок. —  В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007».

«Дело выгорело — кто либо победил, добился своего, всё устроил. Выражение связано с судопроизводством, а именно с ситуациями, когда судебные дела пропадали в результате пожара, часто устроенного намеренно, за взятки судившегося. Тогда виноватого нельзя было наказать, а правого оправдать.   Справочник по фразеологии.2013».

Толкование кажется понятным и вопросов не вызывает, но предполагаемая версия происхождения «из судопроизводства» (https://www.otrezal.ru/catch-words/112.html) приводит к несуразице: «Истец, ну что вы все обиваете пороги суда? Папка с вашим делом давно с(вы)горела при пожаре и потому ваше дело не выгорело, а дело ответчика, напротив, - выгорело…».

Что бы развеять возникшие сомнения, пришлось поискать (в корпусе русского языка) примеров в подтверждение существующей точки зрения на происхождение «дело выгорело» и заодно посчитать число имеющихся упоминаний слова «выгорело» в его необычном значении: все «удалось», «получилось», «вышло», «сбылось» «пошло на лад» «не сорвалось».

Итоги таковы:

- «дело … выгорело» и «выгорело … дело» - 23 (1),
- «дело … не выгорело» и «не выгорело … дело» - 35 (1),
- «… не выгорело …» 55 (2),
- «…выгорело…» 5 (1).

В скобках указано число упоминаний, связанных с судопроизводством (всего пять из ста двадцати). 
Следует отметить, что в этих (пяти) упоминаниях «запах гари» не чувствуется. Например:

«Плевако бы осекся, а у меня выгорело. [А. П. Чехов. Староста (1885-1886)]»

«Потому что выгорело бы дело здесь, посадили бы его, сидел бы сейчас, адвокаты бы ему хавчик таскали, жил бы, как король, в камере. [Андрей Белозеров. Чайка (2001)]»

Судя по числу упоминаний, ключевым является выражение «не выгорело». Оно и наиболее часто упоминаемое, и самое раннее из всех:

«Явление третье [Степан, муж] (один) Должно быть, опять не выгорело! Эх, жизнь, жизнь! [А. Н. Островский. Не в свои сани не садись (1852)]».

Нетрудно видеть, что «дело» здесь только подразумевается. Однако, если речь идет о «деле» в его конкретных значениях: затея, начинание, предприятие, бизнес, то без этого слова уже не обойтись:

«А вот послушай-ка, Аксинья, что я вздумал: сегодня у меня на базаре дельце выгорело ― пшеницу на Низу в годы беру, землю, то есть, казенную на сроки хочу нанимать. [П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга первая (1871-1874)]».

«Тут и другие придворные, видя, что левши дело выгорело, начали его целовать, а Платов ему сто рублей дал и говорит: [Н. С. Лесков. Левша (1881)]».

«То есть дело выгорело совершенно в другую сторону, вовсе не туда, куда хороший человек метил». [Г. И. Успенский. Умерла за «направление» (1879)]»

В результате поиска в корпусе РЯ, не удалось найти подтверждений объяснению происхождения выражений «дело выгорело / не выгорело» через связь с судопроизводством (которое встречается повсеместно и попало даже в Справочник по фразеологии.2013).

На мой взгляд следовало бы обратить внимание на бытующее и сегодня выражение «гореть желанием», имеющее значения: жаждать, мечтать (строить планы), очень хотеть, стремиться.

Это выражение употребляется с давних пор:

«Наконец скучили ушам его похвалы окружающих отца его, и он признавал их льстецами, их состояние чтил ниже своего и потому горел желанием (72) прославиться и хвалимым быти повсюду. [неизвестный. Пословицы российские (1782)]»

«Я сам горю желанием писать трагедию, и рукой моей погибнут по крайней мере с полдюжины героев, а если рассержусь, то и ни одного живого человека на театре не оставлю. [Д. И. Фонвизин. Письма родным (1763-1774)]»

Как видим, выражение «гореть желанием» на полвека старше, чем «выгорело / не выгорело», да и по своему смыслу вполне может претендовать на роль прямого предка.

Если все так, то первично выражение «гореть желанием», откуда произошло «(не) выгорело», которое уже трансформировалось в «дело (не) выгорело».

Где же таятся примеры, указывающие на связь выражения «дело выгорело» с судопроизводством? Может быть они есть в иноязычных источниках?